# Skewed background and hover-effect with hidden overflow

Tags: html, css, navigation

I am working on a CSS3-navigation, but I have some troubles with the overflow of the hover-effect.
I tried to add `overflow:hidden` - without success.

This is what it looks like:
[image]

And this is what it should look like:
[image]

HTML:

```
<header>
<div id="header-top">
    <nav id="main-navigation" role="navigation">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Artists</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header-top {
    height: 70px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}
#header-top:after {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
    content: "";
    height: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    left: 0px;
    transform: skewY(-4deg);
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
#main-navigation ul {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#main-navigation ul li {
    display: inline;
    line-height: 30px;
}
#main-navigation ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
}
#main-navigation ul li a:hover {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/v9dfjq4L/1/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put the background color on the `header` and use the `:after` element to clip the bottom of the `#header-top`.
http://jsfiddle.net/ovtphrqL/
[image]

```
#header-top:after {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    content: "";
    height: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 74px;
    left: 0px;
    transform: skewY(-3deg);
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to play with clip-path and mask. Here are some useful links:

[**Link 1**](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/)

[**Link 2**](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-masking/)

Answer (score 1):

**Problem explanation:**

`overflow: hidden` will indeed not work, because you applied the skewY to the :after element, which doesn't influence the rest of the content of #header-top.

**However, I found thissolution to your problem:**

Remove the :after thing. Apply the `skewY(-4deg)` and background-color to the `<nav>`, and invert this transform for the inner `<ul>` using `skewY(4deg)`. Now, `overflow: hidden` will work when applied to the `<nav>`.

A few new problems turn up: a little white triangle in the left top corner (fix: `padding-top` and negative `margin-top` for the `<nav>`), and the red hover isn't high enough for some items (fix: use a bigger `padding-bottom`).

Don't forget to use a crossbrowser fallback for transform (-webkit-, -moz-, -o-).

**Applied solution:**

This solution is applied in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v9dfjq4L/9/